# AD Account not working

Tags: macos, user-account, active-directory

For a few days now I cannot login to AD Accounts anymore.
I receive the message
"Your are unable to log in to the user account "XYZ" at this time.
Logging into the account failed because an error occurred"

I've logged in with a local administrator to check the AD Connection and this seems to work.

After this I've checked the directory services. If I go to the directory editor and search for the user in the nodename. I can find it with all attributes.

Unfortunately we are running macOS High Sierra 10.13.

Time/Date is also checked.

All neccessary certificates are installed.

Comment: Anything relevant in the system logs, both on Mac and on AD server side?

Comment: I've already checked the system logs. There is nothing. If i try some network services like network share with this ad user, it is working. Only the login did'nt work

Comment: We are dealing with *Windows* here, so I would verify the account is not disabled or locked out by disabling and re-enabling the account, locking/unlocking it. Also check the logs on your DC to look for login failures on that or other accounts.

Comment: The Problem was, that the home drive from the user, which is defined in AD was not accessible during start up. I've unchecked the option to connect it and then it was working.